# How to sort a string in Android

Tags: android, string, sorting, alphabetical

I have a string like `"RSEBAK"` and I'd like to sort that string to `"ABEKRS"`

Is it possible in android?

If it is, then please guide me through.

Comment: yes, is that the answer you are looking for? You have to elaborate your questions. Maybe you should first try to understand how stackoverflow works. take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: durgesh, I answered below. But notice that you got several downvotes so want to say you will get better answers on StackOverflow if you work on describing the question well. Hoping I understood, but I think many more would have answered if the question was "How can I alphebetize a string" or something slong that line. Also, may be quicker on questions like this to Google. I suspect this on would not be hard to find. Anyway, not raggin, just hoping to improve your experience here. :-)

Comment: Yes. Actually, you can do that in pretty much any system these days. True fact. The question is, **Why, and according to which rules?**

Answer (score 2):

Your spec is a bit fuzzy, but I think you mean to sort the charters in a string? If so…

```
String s1 = "RSEBAK";
char[] arrC = s1.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(arrC);
String strSorted = new String(arrC);
```

strSorted should have "ABEKRS"